# What is the best way to manipulate messed up csv data extracted from PDF

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pdf, tabula

I have this csv file loaded into lists. as

```
dataFromFile = list(csv.reader(f))
```

Each value is supposed to be single list element that I can later manipulate easily. But as you can see some values are merged into 1. Like [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UldpH.jpg). And some just miss there spot totally , like [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UldpH.jpg).
Right now i do all manipulation by hardkoding, moving, merging, splitinf deleting for each line. I wonder if there is a nice and handy tool to help me with this job? 
All the data comes from tabula-py. Rest of the pages look handy,but this one is broken.

```
All
0 ['', 'Mar 2017', 'Dec 2016', 'Sept 2016', 'Jun 2016', 'Mar 2016']
1 ['Earnings growth*', '6.9%', '5.6% (2.1%)', '7.2%', '11.1%', '-0.3%']
2 ['', '12.7%', '', '', '']
3 ['Capital spending', '4.1% Median = 7.5% 3.2% (6.8%)', '5.5%', '6.1%', '']
4 ['Advertising and', '', '', '', '']
5 ['marketing spending', '', '', '', '']
6 ['', '2.0% 1.9% (1.7%)', '2.2%', '6.1%', '4.8%']
7 ['Technology spending', '5.9% 5.3% (6.7%)', '6.8%', '8.2%', '5.6%']
8 ['R&D spending', '3.9% 4.4% (5.1%)', '3.9%', '7.4%', '4.5%']
9 ['Employment û full-time', '5.1% 6.0% (2.7%)', '1.0%', '0.5%', '-0.2%']
10 ['Wages and Salaries', '5.3% 6.8% (6.7%)', '3.8%', '6.3%', '4.2%']
11 ['Inflation (Chg in prices of 0.1% own-firm products)', '3.4% 2.6% 1.2% (1.3%)', '-1.2% Median=0%', 'Median=2%', '']
12 ['Health Care Costs', '4.3% 2.7% (3.9%)', '2.0%', '4.1%', '4.0%']
13 ['Revenue', '3.7% 6.3% (7.3%)', '4.2%', '5.4%', '0.4%']
14 ['', 'Compared to last qtr.', 'Compared to last qtr.', 'Compared to last qtr.', 'Compared to last qtr.', 'Compared to last qtr.']
15 ['Optimism about', 'More opt: 33.9%', 'More opt: 29.1%', 'More opt: 32.5%', 'More opt: 36.2%', 'More opt: 32.5%']
16 ['the countryÆs', 'Less opt: 35.7%', 'Less opt: 37.6%', 'Less opt: 35.3%', 'Less opt: 44.3%', 'Less opt: 47.3%']
17 ['economy', 'No chg: 30.4%', 'No chg: 33.3%', 'No chg: 32.2%', 'No chg: 19.5%', 'No chg: 20.1%']
18 ['Country optimism', '', '', '', '', '']
19 ['level', '57.6', '58.6', '65.0', '56.8', '56.9']
20 ['Optimism about', 'More opt: 40.7%', 'More opt: 35.6%', 'More opt: 36.7%', 'More opt: 39.7%', 'More opt: 41.3%']
21 ['own company', 'Less opt: 25.8% No chg: 33.6%', 'Less opt: 35.3% No chg: 29.2%', 'Less opt: 30.4% No chg: 32.9%', 'Less opt: 33.2% No chg: 27.2%', 'Less opt: 37.1% No chg: 21.6%']
22 ['Own company', '', '', '', '', '']
23 ['optimism level', '59.9', '60.8', '66.7', '61.6', '60.7']
```

After processing I expect csv file of the following format and with suvh info.

[image]

Comment: What is the desired output? there is a lot going on that is making it difficult for me to grasp what the end result should look like. Also, what will the end goal of this data be? The answers to both of these questions will really help guide our answers

Comment: @MattR   Updated description.